# How do I know how big to make my array for Parcel.readStringArray()?

Tags: android, parcel

I'm getting a null pointer exception when I do this:

```
    private String[] foo;

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        in.readStringArray(foo);
    }
```

It seems I need to allocate the array first.  But how do I know how big to make it?  Do I have to write the size first and then read the size first?  And isn't the point of having a `writeStringArray()` method to handle this for me?

From the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html):

> There are a variety of methods for reading and writing raw arrays of primitive objects, which generally result in writing a 4-byte length followed by the primitive data items.

So, if I write the count myself, it's getting written twice.  There must be some way of doing this where I am not responsible for managing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is not a direct answer, but you can use lists (`ArrayList<String>`) instead with `writeList()` and `createStringArrayList()`.

Or you could use [`Parcle#createStringArray()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createStringArray%28%29) to get the array.

Comment: Well, the problem is the underlying data type is tied to a schema that spans multiple components.  And it's a `String[]`.  I could write code to convert it to an `ArrayList<>` and back, but I shouldn't have to.

Comment: And what about `createStringArray`?

Comment: Ah, that looks like what I need.  Let me test it.

Comment: Yeah, I knew there had to be away.  My psychic powers failed me on the name.

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect you'd have to do something like this:

```
private String[] foo;
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        int cnt = in.readInt();
        foo = new String[cnt];
        in.readStringArray(foo);
    }
```

which implies you have to record the size of the array when writing out.